# Is there a way to describe a Message type structure using generics?

Tags: typescript, generics

It is necessary to describe the interface of the following structure

```
interface Message {
   type: <any string const such as const STR_CONST = 'lalala' as const>;
   payload: <any object>
}
```

for messages not known at the moment - for using in library

It should validate messages like Messages:

```
const READY = 'READY' as const;
function getReady(ready: boolean) {
   return {
      type: READY,
      payload: {
        ready
      }
   }
}
      
type Messages = ReturnType<typeof getReady> | <...other type>;
```

playground is here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK6dudAGwJYCNQGMD2ATAphPETALABQyAdgC54BOAZgIYYEDqWdA1vQLJ4BnAUwDmBAN7lQ00NQCeABzwAuUAOp0qIgNxSZCpnMRYmOVQCU82OjgA86zZRGgAPqEoBXALap6AGlAmSjkAPl0yAF9yciZUBxZqTEQmIVAAIRS8Dm56UEkyGVAFOixaDFocUAB3Th46VWy611APSnwGKjwccL1pbEoHD3LOAAoanPrQRvoASjzewtkAC2QBADpxpoBeatr6HoLF6WoV9c36NdMcAFEANzwaABlV2kp6EYByL0FhMQ+Ak6rNZYSj8ISiPAzcKFKJkBbFUpWCqgEFg34EHYjPD3GiqNEQu4Pai2aZ0fFiEJzLYheaHI50PDUDx0SjQmQRcKw8ggQjEPnEQIKBSYXAEfl86JkPAADwUnES-XUUwA8uYANLXcwAfQAkgBlLXma4AQQAIgBNUA7D5sVUa7X6w0mi0fQICEUDajhBitcrIEGgBmmOTkvAjIM4OSqVBYLCIPBBOb5QoMpks2lHY6KFQq9Wa3UGo1m81+BaFAxGExmPKBhOR0ARUt0hucyXyJRTPZkn4Q91bBZuSxpygAFWztnbeCwDFrwdDIUlGGSqRHSzwliYiAAwsv3TLXjh3RkBFkuxmZIqNENqKNzpNSUmyzIBB4lHQxl2oQsuc2EWVkVg9x0Jo+AoqCPZiFaoBYji1B4hBeCEjQJJdqGAiUqotxYMglTUueRwCFUyDUBgSzQdiRJrDgTDUEwayTo+zaZpgmS5vaBZOsWqjJsxmaKnGeBrMYIgwZR1G0WsFbGKYawRnIMxPrxoCoEGXBskpP5KdI7RMB4iBwYpvEqQmamGbCMKSj+l67BMUFvFUoCruuCbbruIz2Z2EyfMAd5rAAVgIHwzDMQA

Comment: "any string const" - `type: string` and "any object" - `payload: any`? Could you clarify what problem you've had here? Also note the `as const` on the first line is totally pointless - the type is _already_ inferred as `'READY'`, because it's a `const`.

Comment: type: string <> type: string constant

Comment: Assuming what you actually mean is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then: if you have a more specific type, by all means use that. But again it's unclear what the actual problem is. What do you think should be generic? Where would the type argument be coming from?

Comment: the module at the declaration stage does not know which specific types will be used, so I ask how to describe it using generics

Comment: I can only suggest reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html. Maybe you want `payload: T` to be inferred from something, it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve and you don't seem to have tried making _anything_ generic.

Comment: the problem is extremely simple: in the library, I need to describe the type of messages using generics, and in the code, when using the library, substitute a specific union type of messages and so that there are no errors - everything is displayed in the text of the question.
Messages  should be passed as valid subtype of Message
The first problem is in that type: string <> type: string constant

Comment: Great, then you'll certainly be able to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240507/discussion-between-vadim-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: I'm also confused, could you take [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wOzp7W) and edit it so that it clearly demonstrates what doesn't work about it?  It is true that `string` is wider than any specific string literal type, but it's not obvious why you care.  There should be some piece of code you can point at and show that `string` yields an error or some other problem.  Good luck!

Comment: here is a playground https://shorturl.at/hlzB4

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me like this is what you want: a `Message` creator function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=27&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcwgHgBUBPABxQgA9IQATDZDMKUHAGmQAU5iAbAezi1kAXmQBXEAGsQ-AO4gAfMgDeAKGSawZCAC5kJcgG4Nm0jwFD93PoNomAvmrUxJCMMH4hkCKBDiQ6Fi4KEQ6yFQ09IzMrBw2lsJikjLySgAUptrk+oYQbKbmtkKiEnQQMKAQwnAMKbIKyLVcFnYFAJT6Qdh4YeTxrULK6pp+YOJQ3irZ+chFiQ6OzgheTMh+QsTdIaW+-oGYPRDpAOQASgCiAIIAIgCaJxwqc1D8pPonAG5wvOIQJ8gHO0TBtaFtDiEAHQzZAAelhyAARJdbndEWpQeDgnhIfM7HCEc9SK93jEWCAcIDlqswIwIGBtnhdhsDtjjicAMoXQiPVTIWjAGAwaAQcCcEn6ACMACZAcC1Bh6YyINDwvCkVzCOjFQyITi8SV1c8BUKRWKJcgQOIALYAI2gVLUKxAaxw-GVzP2EGVpwA4gB5E7yt3K1XkAlIgPokN6lUG4Tq+ppaku2n8KQesR7ALe2Onf0AaV5JwA6igBcJgGAAIRBkzp0Mw9WIwvohux3GDBMIpjknBqIA)

```ts
interface Message<Type extends string, Payload = unknown> {
   type: Type;
   payload: Payload;
}

function createMessage <Type extends string, Payload = unknown>(
  type: Type,
  payload = undefined as unknown as Payload,
): Message<Type, Payload> {
  return {type, payload};
}

const readyMessage = createMessage('READY', { prop: 'value' });
readyMessage.type // "READY"
readyMessage.payload // { prop: string }

const setMessage = createMessage('SET', { differentProp: 12 });
setMessage.type // "SET"
setMessage.payload // { differentProp: number }

const goMessage = createMessage('GO');
goMessage.type // "GO"
goMessage.payload // unknown

const okMessage = createMessage('OK', 'We did it!');
okMessage.type // "OK"
okMessage.payload // string
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try

Comment: its unclear for me how should I describe the message type in a library method?
`
protected onMessage = (event: MessageEvent<Message???>) => {
        return;
};
`
could you fix the mine playground please?

Comment: @Vadim `onMessage = <Type extends string, Payload>(event: MessageEvent<Message<Type, Payload>>)`

Comment: > Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"READY"'
https://shorturl.at/ehAW8